# Can't find msgbox code (Deleted it) but msgbox still appears

Tags: ms-access, msgbox

I haven't even been able to find anyone with this problem online, let alone a solution!

I had several msgboxes in some VBA code I was writing to provide feedback for debugging. After a while the code was stable and I commented out the MsgBox lines.

One set of msgboxes wouldn't vanish though. I even deleted it rather than removing it. In the end I decided I must have a duplication somewhere, somehow, even though all the related code ended up calling this specific function where I'd removed the MsgBox.

I couldn't see any other explanation as I'd literally deleted the lines of code. I searched the entire project for fragments of the string which formed part of the MsgBox's text. Ctrl + F, set to search entire project, tried with and without pattern matching.

I found literally nothing. I decided the string must be more constructed than I thought, and instead opted to search using 'MsgBox' to search through every time I had used the command. I checked every single MsgBox in every project file and found nothing even remotely like the debugging message the code was still generating.

Anyone have any other ideas what may be going on? My best theory is that I've somehow hidden or duplicated something, but aside from depreciating a form whose code doesn't contain a single MsgBox or call code which does, I've done nothing I can think of to cause this.

I'd paste the code but you'd still just be taking my word for it that the MsgBox isn't there.

Can anyone help? It has to be hiding in there somewhere, somehow.

Many thanks,

Code where the MsgBox originally appeared (it provided feedback based on the RecordSet's NoMatch property):

```
Public Function createRecordSnapshot(Table As String, dbRefIn As String, payNum As String)


Dim fieldNames As String
Dim oldDataSet As String
Dim rs As Recordset
Dim fieldCount As Integer
Dim recordTot As Integer
Dim srchString As String


Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(Table, dbOpenDynaset)
srchString = "DBRef = '" & dbRefIn & "' and PayrollRef = '" & payNum & "'"
fieldCount = rs.Fields.Count
rs.FindFirst (srchString)
Dim o As Integer

For o = 0 To fieldCount - 1
    fieldNames = fieldNames & rs.Fields(o).Name & "|"
Next o

For o = 0 To fieldCount - 1
    oldDataSet = oldDataSet & rs.Fields(o).Value & "|"
Next o

createRecordSnapshot = fieldNames & vbNewLine & oldDataSet

End Function
```

Comment: MsgBox's don't just show up without code triggering them so it's clearly in the code somewhere...without showing us any of the code we aren't going to be able to help you.

Comment: Given I've already removed it from the code section it appeared in I don't see how it will help. I need a way to find wherever it is hiding. If it will help though, the code was originally here providing feedback as to the NoMatch property of the record set:

Comment: Maybe VBA is calling a macro and it has [MessageBox Macro Action](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/messagebox-macro-action-af01a015-8b69-4be0-a4ab-57bc32497c31)?

Comment: @DávidLaczkó, None that I can find with a ctrl+F, search entire project search. There isn't a whole lot of code present either.

Comment: Try after re-compilation of the code (in the Debug menu there is an option to compile)

Comment: @DávidLaczkó - that seems to have done the trick! I'll need to do some more testing tomorrow to be certain, but at the very least the MsgBoxes have stopped appearing. Thanks friend, I owe you a beer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a modification it is good practice to re-compile the code manually, as it makes running the code faster (can skip the compilation on next run) and refreshes previously compiled code. The option is in the VB Editor's Debug menu.